# Sleep, rest and meditation?

Tags: meditation, meditation-effects, sleep

I’m wondering what your meditation practice’s effects are on your sleep. I’m asking this because I have a strange tendency, habit of waking up with very troubled thoughts and memories of past hardships. I’m meditating before and after sleep not only for spiritual goals but also for the purposes of relaxing and letting go of these thoughts.

What are you experiences? Do you know if Buddha had anything to say on this matter?  I would love to hear what you have to say!

Thank you for your kindness,

A Buddhist

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many effects of meditation on sleep. Similarly to you, before and after sleep.

I have had times when my need for sleep is vastly reduced, and I've had times when I don't want to do anything but sleep.

It seems meditation can release stuff. Sometimes it seems to release a kind of 'repressed tiredness' that just needs time to get out. Sometime it releases energy that means sleep need is reduced.

As I've said on another post, what would it be like if, when you wake from sleep with troubled thoughts, you take the time to turn towards those thoughts, and importantly the feelings that go with them, with kindness, gentleness and care? The troubledness, in my experience, is just something in me asking for attention. Wonders can happen when you pay less attention to the rational content of the thoughts, and more attention to the emotional content.